# Setting up existing membership with mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an existing SQL membership db that I used with webforms, I am trying set it up to work with mvc4 but with no luck, when I try to get user by id(I know this user exists) I get null exception.And web I open web app config I can clearly see it has no members or roles..etc.

Here is part of config from my web froms app :

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=myserver;Initial Catalog=mydb;User ID=myid;Password=mypwd" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
      <properties>
        <add name="UrgentPoints" type="System.Int32" defaultValue="0" />
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
        <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
....
```

And here is for mvc:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=myserver;Initial Catalog=mydb;User ID=myid;Password=mypwd" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
          enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
          requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
          minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
          applicationName="/" name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager>
      <providers>
        <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"
          name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: MVC 4 using some extra Store Procedure to verify account. I've this error "Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'."  Any body known some tools to migrate to new Member Data ?

Comment: @ThantZin If you are setting up new MVC4 provider tables you don't have to use aspnet_regsql.exe tool, delete any tables you created with that. Now change connection string in you web confing file. After that, startup ASP.NET Configuration and after setup you will have new tables. The comment/answer provided by me below answer aplies if you already had old provider tables in your database and you are switching to MVC4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First be sure to switch to Asp.Net Universal Providers (nuget package) and then be sure to connect to the same DB as the old application. The schema for the asp.net db hasn't changed and should work fine with MVC 4.

Comment: Actually I found out what is the problem, MVC4 apparently use different membership providers so I just had to switch to old ones,from System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider to System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider and same from roles and profile.

Comment: Strange, I have seen the solution proposed by Israel Lot elsewhere too, and it seems to work for some people, but it is not working for me. I keep getting an error message saying "The user name or password provided is incorrect". I haven't tried replacing DefaultProfileProvider by SqlMembershipProvider though. I would have liked to be able to use the DefaultProfileProvider. In the end, I kept using the old ASP.Net Membership provider, and I modified my controller accordingly.

Answer (score 22):

Here is my way after 3 days Googling. Using MVC4 RC, .net Framework 4.5, SQL Server Express with new `SqlMemberDB` created by .NET 4 cause old SqlMemberDB missing some stored procedure.

1. add in one more setting to `<AppSetting>` as below to disable "simple membership":

   ```
   <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
   ```
2. add in database connection as required. I'm using SQL Server 2000, so disable user instance.

   ```
   <add name="ScqMember_Context" 
        connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MemberDB;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;Integrated Security=False;User Instance=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   ```
3. copy setting configuration from machine.ini under v4 .NET framework.

   ```
   <membership>
       <providers>
           <clear/>
           <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
                type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
                connectionStringName="ScqMember_Context" 
                enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" 
                requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" 
                requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" 
                maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" 
                minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" 
                passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
       </providers>
   </membership>
   <profile>
       <providers>
           <clear/>
           <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" 
                connectionStringName="ScqMember_Context" 
                applicationName="/" 
                type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
       </providers>
   </profile>
   <roleManager enabled="true">
       <providers>
           <clear />
           <add connectionStringName="ScqMember_Context" 
                applicationName="/"
                name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" 
                type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
       </providers>
   </roleManager>
   ```
4. Change Login() from Account Controller as below

   ```
    /// aspnetSQLMember Authentication
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);

            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        }
    }
   ```
5. Update Logoff module from AccountController as below

   ```
   /// aspnetSQLMember Authentication
   FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
   ```

Thanks,

Comment: thanks for the tips for disabling simplemembership. I have a case where I don't use simplemembership and it always throws exception Unable to connect to SQL server after logging in successfully and redirect to intended page. Thanks again!

Comment: I believe the Register() function in the AccountController needs to be modified as well.

Comment: Plus, the Manage() functions in the AccountController too.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same problem - pointing the MVC4 application to an "old" aspnet database. Existing users/passwords are not able to be retrieved under the "default" settings (System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider) -> note these passwords are encrypted and the appropriate settings are present in the local web.config (under system.web)

```
<machineKey
  validationKey= "A3..."
  decryptionKey= "8B..."
  validation="SHA1"
  decryption="AES"/>
```

If I add a new user with the "DefaultProfileProvider" that user can be reconciled and authenticated - it just doesn't work with existing users that were added with the "old" provider methinks.

I haven't had the chance to "switch" to the old but I would suspect that it works (thanks user1010609)
@Israel - It is odd and it should work - but it doesn't ;)

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you must to include in the references of your project the library: 
**System.Web.Providers.dll**