# LazyInitializer exception in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

i have created new MVC 4  web application and tried to run it . But im getting some exception in

```
 LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
```

and i could not navigate to the Register or Login page .I have selected  **Internet application** and

[image]

what went wrong . Can any one help me

Comment: Database initialization went wrong.

Comment: @AgentFire  I dint even added any code nor modified . I just created new MVC application and running it

Comment: There is might be an error in your SQL express database, or even lack of one. You should manually initialize your database.

Comment: Check out this one:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877318/setting-up-existing-membership-with-mvc4

Answer (score 0):

Just delete that whole row and your application will run.

Delete this:

```
LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
```

If you want to setup existing membership then refer this:
[Setting up existing membership with mvc4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877318/setting-up-existing-membership-with-mvc4)

Comment: Which row i have to delete . Explain a bit

Comment: @whoah if you delete that then your your application will run and you can use you own logic to perform login, register etc. And if you don't want to delete then refer to link mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple just go to your web.config in the connectionstring tag add this tag with your own connectionstring

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score -1):

for 99% problem is here (of course don't delete this row):

```
  WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "Users", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

You have a problem with your database, as @AgentFire said in comments. 
Can you show trackstack of error and line in `Web.Confing` responsible for database connection? Also it could be an error caused by lack of SQL express database.

Comment: Okay how can i overcome this