# MVC 4 and ASP.NET Membership

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

I am having issues understanding what I need to do with this and how to get them to interact.

I have created an MVC 4 Internet Application. From what I understand, the login mechanism uses the SimpleMembershipProvider which is not compatible with the SQL based ASP.NET Membership provider.

I have an existing site that uses ASP.NET Membership and we are going to be leveraging this. I only need a login controller. The User name is being passed in by the original application that is calls my new application. This is all on an intranet, and we are creating a simple SSO model.

From what I can tell I will need to add in the "DefaultMembershipProvider" entry into the web.config and create a connection string to my membership DB. I have that much.

But I am unclear as to what the code will need to look like for the controller.

Here is the code that I currently have for the controller for the simple provider:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult LoginAuto(string userid)
    {
        LoginModel model = new LoginModel();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userid))
        {
            model.UserName = userid;
            model.RememberMe = true;
            model.Password = "Dude!!!!1";

            if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            model.UserName = "";
        }



        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View("Login", model);
    }
```

Will I need to change this at all? Will the actual controller class be different from what comes with the template? I'm pretty new to the actual security thing and looking for some direction.

Thanks.

Comment: I wanted to let you all that I found a solution, right here on Stack Overflow. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877318/setting-up-existing-membership-with-mvc4